# C# Run SQL Parameterized query - parameter not suplied

Tags: c#, sql

I have a c# application. I am trying to run a parameterized query, please see below. However I keep getting the error message

> "The parameterized query '(@dtStart date)SELECT * FROM
>   D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI WHERE [date_effe' expects the parameter '@dtStart',
>   which was not supplied."

I can't see why it is telling me this though?

```
DateTime dtStart = dtPrev;

using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
     _connection.Open();
     string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI " + 
                      "WHERE [date_effective] >= @dtStart " +
                      "AND [ca_status] ='" + caStatus + "'";

     _command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, _connection);
     _command.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date);
```

Comment: You have to assign a value to `@dtStart`, where did you do that?

Comment: (And then fix the caStatus to be a parameter as well...)

Comment: Ahh yes! Now I feel stupid! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Parameters.Add` try `Parameters.AddWithValue`

```
 _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtStart", dtStart);
```

Or give a value to your parameter:

```
 _command.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStart;
```